# ParserError: Expected event name or path

Tags: solidity, tokens, crowdsale

I have a lot of experience in programming but I'm a noob when it comes to ethereum programming. When I try to compile the code with truffle I have this error: `ParserError: Expected event name or path` on lines where I use events `EthTransfered` and `EthRefunded`.

My source code: https://github.com/amiramieng/simplebyte-contract/blob/master/contracts/SimpleByteTokenCrowdsale.sol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the dot after emit

Call events like so:

```
emit EthTransferred('forwarding funds to wallet')
```

Instead of

```
emit.EthTransferred('...')
```

Comment: What about this one? `TypeError: Member "forwardFunds" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract super SimpleByteTokenCrowdsale
          super.forwardFunds();`

Comment: quick guess: add an underscore as that's what the super function is called in crowdsale.sol :

super._forwardFunds();